# Sagemaker usage of EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker

Is there a way to view/monitor AWS Sagemaker's usage of EC2 instances?
I am running a Sagemaker endpoint and tried to find its instances (ml.p3.2xlarge in this case) in the EC2 UI, but couldn't find them.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the EC2 instance? They don't appear in the EC2 UI and API as they are being managed by the SageMaker control plane.

Comment: Would give me better understanding oh what's happening behind the scenes (e.g. trying to tackle permission issues) - which security groups and roles are in play, when were the instances launched etc.

Comment: The IAM role (permissions) are defined by you when you are launching the SageMaker instance. You can use the combination of SageMaker API (launch date is there as well) and open the Terminal from the Jupyter interface to get the most of what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ml EC2 instances do not appear in the EC2 console. You can find their metrics in Cloudwatch though, and create dashboards to monitor what you need:

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is unfortunately true just for endpoints, but not for notebook instances.

Comment: @mkostelac  That's right. I don't think there's any standard way to monitor notebooks.